# Duration of binary serialization increased after serialize and deserialize an object in json serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, deep-copy

I've used NewtonSoft.Json to serialize an object and save it into a file. This object contains the whole data of a project created in my software. I read this file (deserialize) and create my project object if needed later. Previously, I used Binary serialization for this purpose, but the problem was that I could not read a saved file on another computer, so I changed it to Json type serialization. I also used compression for the output file to decrease its size.

JSON Serialization:

```cs
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project, setting: new JsonSerializer() { Formatting = Formatting.None, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore});
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
using (FileStream outputFS = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
{
   using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(outputFS, CompressionMode.Compress))
   {
       compressionStream.Write(inputeBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
   }
}
```

JSON Deserialization:

```cs
string jsonString = string.Empty;
using (FileStream inputFS = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
   using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(inputFS, CompressionMode.Decompress))
   {
      using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
         byte[] outputBytes = new byte[4096];
         int bytesRead;
         while ((bytesRead = decompressionStream.Read(outputBytes, 0, outputBytes.Length)) > 0)
         {
            outputStream.Write(outputBytes, 0, bytesRead);
         }
         jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());
      }
   }
}
Project proj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(jsonString);
```

In some parts of my software, I have to create a deep copy (clone) from my project object.
For this matter, I use `BinaryFormatter` using the below method:

```cs
public static T DeepCopy<T>(T other)
{
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      formatter.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone);
      formatter.Serialize(ms, other);
      ms.Position = 0;
      return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
   }
}
```

Previously, using the binary saving method, creating the clone after reading a saved file was quick. Right now, after I read a JSON-type saved file, the cloning process takes a lot of time. I checked the project object as much as I could and there is no difference before saving and after reading (at least anything visual is the same).
Does anyone know the reason that caused this delay in cloning after reading the project object?

Comment: If you do not need human readable data you might consider binary serialization, like protobuf-net. That should be faster than json+compression, and the size should be a lot less than raw json, so compression should be a lot less important. Another alternative is json in a *zip file*, this makes it fairly easy to read/edit the file by hand, and also allow storage of multiple files, so you do not necessarily need to deserialize everything in one go.

Comment: If you are mostly concerned about performance issues I would suggest using a profiler to check what is actually causing the delay. That is much more effective than having random people on the internet making guesses.

Comment: Shameless self promotion: as a `BinaryFormatter` replacement you can try [this](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_BinarySerializationFormatter.htm) serializer from [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries) package. Not just safer and faster but also much more [compact](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQfFrQ) than `BinaryFormatter`. But for deep cloning [this](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/M_KGySoft_CoreLibraries_ObjectExtensions_DeepClone__1_1.htm) extension (from the same library) is actually more preferable (and even faster).

Comment: The problem with deep cloning by general `IFormatter` serialization is that it works only on serializable types (without using a surrogate selector), but even a lot of types that used to be serializable in .NET Framework, now throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.